# Can you fill a life bubble with water?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, starfinder

I am looking to use *life bubble* in both Pathfinder and Starfinder. 
I'm trying to figure out a way for *life bubble* to contain salt water.

#### Is it possible to put a void zombie in a bubble with holy water / salt water?

Answer (score 15):

The description of Life Bubble reads, in part:

> You surround the touched creatures with a constant and moveable 1-inch shell of tolerable living conditions. This shell enables the subjects to breathe freely, even underwater or in a vacuum, as well as making them immune to harmful gases and vapors, including inhaled diseases and poisons...

Life Bubble creates a habitable and tolerable living environment for the target. It doesn't matter what that creature needs, it gets it. If the target can only live in salt water than it will be filled with salt water, etc.

The Bubble can't be used offensively, because only those things that make the environment tolerable for the creature are retained within it.

Comment: ...and now I have to wonder if you could use it on one creature, who might appreciate something like noxious gasses or lava, and then have that creature use it offensively against someone else with a touch attack.

Comment: @BenBarden Ooooh, I like that idea.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you gave one to say, a methane breathing creature and then lit a match near it...

Comment: Can it be used defensively?

Comment: @BenBarden I posit that "tolerable living conditions" means that you'd have to find a creature that can ONLY survive in noxious gas or lava to get a bubble filled with unusual matter, and can't tolerate living outside of said condition (you can tolerate a lot of conditions, you just might not be perfectly comfortable). I don't think there's many of those in Pathfinder.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy That would depend on creating the bubble in an oxygen rich atmosphere, and on it allowing the oxygen and methane to mix.  An organism that requires a combustible mix of oxygen and methane as an atmosphere is rather improbable.

Comment: @Justen Yes, it's intended to be a defensive spell.

Comment: Arnt all conditions tolerable for a zombie? Air, water, space.

Comment: zombies and undead dont breathe so can i not provide them water. Then bless or add salt to set water? Life bubble is a harmless effect which seems to be the only spell that can effect a zombie.

Comment: @Justen I think you're confusing the idea of it being a bubble. It's not a tangible bubble that holds things in... it's an ephemeral shell that lets you interact with the world, give and receive items, etc. It's only purpose is to maintain an atmosphere around you that provides livable (or otherwise sustainable for those who came back) conditions where there otherwise wouldn't be.

Comment: Nothing in the spell indicates that you get to select the livable conditions, either. that's up to the GM

Comment: @GnoveltyGnome LavaShark!